Telegram integration with Google Sheets
First post here, not sure how to format my question, but I am trying to make a Telegram Bot, which takes information from messages posted in my Telegram channel, and then puts them into my Google Spreadsheet. I am using Apps Script and I will post the code below which I have currently input. When doing the testDoPost, it works fine and sends a line into my spreadsheet. It is properly deployed, webhook works fine, the web app links fine, everything seems fine, until I get to sending the message in Telegram and then the bot does not react to it in any way. Only prints an error of "last_error_message": "Wrong response from the webhook: 302 Moved Temporarily"
The code is below with the bot token and web app not included. Please let me know how to fix this, it's been killing me for days.
/**
 * Telegram Bot Integration with Google Sheets
 * 
 * This script receives messages from a Telegram bot via webhook,
 * parses specific data from the messages, and appends the data to a Google Sheet.
 * 
 * Ensure you follow the setup instructions below before deploying.
 */

/**
 * Constants
 */
const SHEET_NAME = '...'; // Name of the Google Sheet to append data

/**
 * =========================
 * 1. TOKEN MANAGEMENT
 * =========================
 */

/**
 * Sets the Telegram bot token securely using Properties Service.
 * 
 * IMPORTANT: Run this function **once** to store your Telegram token securely.
 */
function setTelegramToken() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.prompt('Set Telegram Token', 'Please enter your Telegram bot token:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    const token = response.getResponseText().trim();
    if (token) {
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('TELEGRAM_TOKEN', token);
      ui.alert('Success', 'Telegram token has been set successfully.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    } else {
      ui.alert('Error', 'No token provided. Please try again.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    }
  } else {
    ui.alert('Operation cancelled.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}

/**
 * Retrieves the Telegram bot token from Properties Service.
 * 
 * @returns {string} The Telegram bot token.
 */
function getTelegramToken() {
  const token = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('TELEGRAM_TOKEN');
  if (!token) {
    throw new Error('Telegram token not set. Please run setTelegramToken() first.');
  }
  return token;
}

/**
 * =========================
 * 2. WEBHOOK HANDLING
 * =========================
 */

/**
 * Responds to GET requests to verify that the webhook is active.
 * 
 * @param {Object} e - The event parameter.
 * @returns {HtmlOutput} A simple HTML message.
 */
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Webhook is active. This URL is configured to receive Telegram updates.");
}

/**
 * Handles incoming POST requests from Telegram webhook.
 * Parses the message and appends data to Google Sheet if the message format is correct.
 * 
 * @param {Object} e - The event parameter containing POST data.
 * @returns {TextOutput} A JSON response indicating success or error.
 */
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    Logger.log("doPost triggered.");

    // Validate the event object and POST data.
    if (!e || !e.postData || !e.postData.contents) {
      Logger.log("No postData found.");
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'No postData found.' }))
                           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }

    // Log the raw POST data to understand its structure.
    Logger.log("Raw POST Data: " + e.postData.contents);

    // Parse the incoming POST data.
    const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    Logger.log("Parsed Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));

    // Check if the message and text exist.
    if (!data.message || !data.message.text) {
      Logger.log("No message text found.");
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'No message text found.' }))
                           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }

    const message = data.message.text;
    const chatId = data.message.chat.id;
    Logger.log("Message received: " + message);
    Logger.log("Chat ID: " + chatId);

    // Only process messages that start with "#" and contain numbers.
    if (message.startsWith('#') && /\d/.test(message)) {
      // Extract components using regex.
      const targetNumber = message.match(/#(\d+)/); // Extract number after "#"
      const valueBeforeU = message.match(/(\d+)u/); // Extract value before "u"
      const valueBeforeAt = message.match(/(\d+\.\d+)@/); // Extract value before "@"
      const textAfterAt = message.match(/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/); // Extract site after "@"

      Logger.log("Parsed values: " + JSON.stringify({ targetNumber, valueBeforeU, valueBeforeAt, textAfterAt }));

      // Validate all extracted components.
      if (targetNumber && valueBeforeU && valueBeforeAt && textAfterAt) {
        const targetValue = targetNumber[1];
        const uValue = valueBeforeU[1];
        const numberBeforeAt = valueBeforeAt[1];
        const siteName = textAfterAt[1];

        // Append the parsed data to the specified Google Sheet.
        const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
        if (!sheet) {
          Logger.log(`Sheet named "${SHEET_NAME}" not found.`);
          sendTelegramMessage(chatId, `Error: Sheet named "${SHEET_NAME}" not found.`);
          return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'Sheet not found.' }))
                               .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
        }

        sheet.appendRow([targetValue, uValue, numberBeforeAt, siteName]);
        Logger.log("Data appended to sheet successfully.");

        // Respond to the Telegram user confirming the data was recorded.
        sendTelegramMessage(chatId, 'Message recorded successfully.');
      } else {
        // Respond if the message format is incorrect.
        Logger.log("Invalid message format.");
        sendTelegramMessage(chatId, 'Invalid message format. Use #number valueu value@site.');
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log("Message does not start with '#' or does not contain numbers.");
      // Optionally, inform the user about the expected format.
      sendTelegramMessage(chatId, 'Invalid message format. Use #number valueu value@site.');
    }

    // Return a success response to Telegram.
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ status: 'ok' }))
                         .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error in doPost: " + error.message);
    // Respond with an error message.
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: error.message }))
                         .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

/**
 * =========================
 * 3. TELEGRAM COMMUNICATION
 * =========================
 */

/**
 * Sends a message to a Telegram user using the bot's token.
 * 
 * @param {number} chatId - The chat ID to send the message to.
 * @param {string} text - The text message to send.
 */
function sendTelegramMessage(chatId, text) {
  const TELEGRAM_TOKEN = getTelegramToken(); // Retrieve the token securely.
  const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${TELEGRAM_TOKEN}/sendMessage`;
  const payload = {
    chat_id: chatId,
    text: text,
  };
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  };

  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log("sendTelegramMessage response: " + response.getContentText());
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error sending message: ' + error.message);
  }
}

/**
 * =========================
 * 4. WEBHOOK SETUP
 * =========================
 */

/**
 * Sets the webhook for the Telegram bot to point to the Google Apps Script Web App URL.
 * 
 * IMPORTANT: After deploying the Web App, run this function to set the webhook.
 */
function setWebhook() {
  const TELEGRAM_TOKEN = getTelegramToken(); // Retrieve the token securely.
  
  // Replace with your actual deployed Web App URL..
  const webAppUrl = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec; 
  
  const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${TELEGRAM_TOKEN}/setWebhook?url=${encodeURIComponent(webAppUrl)}`;
  
  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    Logger.log('Webhook set successfully: ' + response.getContentText());
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error setting webhook: ' + error.message);
  }
}

/**
 * =========================
 * 5. TESTING FUNCTION
 * =========================
 */

/**
 * Simulates a POST request to the doPost function for testing purposes.
 * 
 * IMPORTANT: Use this function to test doPost without sending actual messages via Telegram.
 */
function testDoPost() {
  const testEvent = {
    postData: {
      contents: JSON.stringify({
        message: {
          text: "#123 45u 67.89@exampleSite",
          chat: {
            id: 123456789 // Replace with a valid chat ID for testing.
          }
        }
      })
    }
  };
  
  doPost(testEvent);
}

I tried absolutely everything, removing the bot, readding it, deleting the webhook, doing setWebhook again and absolutely nothing helps. I am on the verge of giving up but would like some more expert opinions on what could be wrong? The code is done with ChatGPT so I wouldn't doubt it being a bit off rather than a human coding it, but I am pretty clueless when it comes to coding.

Didn't really mind using any tools to generate any code. But would you mind to share your plan on how to check which part works and which part isn't?

Could you elaborate on your plan for identifying which components are functioning correctly and which are not? Sharing your insights on how you intend to isolate the issue would be valuable.
